# Not able to attach the screenshot after failed scenario in Cucumber report Jenkins

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver, jenkins-pipeline, cucumber

I am trying to attach a screenshot after failed scenario in the cucumber report in the Jenkins pipeline. I am running the feature file using selenium, python and Radish framework. Following is the code implementation for the same.

```
@after.each_scenario
    def reportgenerate(scenario, step):
        if scenario.state == "failed":
            screenshot_dir = "./results"
            screenshot_file_path = "{}/{}.png".format(screenshot_dir, scenario.id)
            driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_file_path)
            step.embed(driver.get_screenshot_as_base64(),
               mime_type='image/png',
               encode_data_to_base64=False)
```

Getting this **error** while running the feature file.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/radish/hookregistry.py", line 132, in call
func(model, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: reportgenerate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'step'

Link to the radish framework documentation: https://radish.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html?highlight=screenshot#embedding-data-in-cucumber-report
Also, tried with one argument **scenario**

```
@after.each_scenario
    def reportgenerate(scenario):
        if scenario.state == "failed":
            screenshot_dir = "./results"
            screenshot_file_path = "{}/{}.png".format(screenshot_dir, scenario.id)
            driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_file_path)
            step.embed(driver.get_screenshot_as_base64(),
               mime_type='image/png',
               encode_data_to_base64=False)
```

Then got this **error**,

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/radish/hookregistry.py", line 132, in call
func(model, *args, **kwargs)
File "steps/terrain.py", line 60, in reportgenerate
step.embed(driver.get_screenshot_as_base64(),
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'embed'

Comment: `after.each_scenario` expects a function that only accepts one argument: the scenario. Your function does not match the expected signature because it has two parameters, not one...

Comment: @sytech I tried with one parameter scenario. Then got this error:                            
 **File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/radish/hookregistry.py", line 132, in call
    func(model, *args, **kwargs)
  File "steps/terrain.py", line 60, in reportgenerate
    step.embed(driver.get_screenshot_as_base64(),
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'embed'**

Comment: Because you're trying to call `step.embed` but you have no local `step` object. I assume `step` is defined somewhere else in your file, but it's not what you're expecting. If you want to use `step.embed` you probably want to use `@after.every_step` instead of every scenario. I'm not sure there's a way to get both the scenario object and step object at the same time. So the code you have isn't going to work. It seems to me you'd either need to remove the code relying on `step` object and use `after.every_scenario` or remove the code relying on the `scenario` object and use `after.every_step`

Comment: @sytech Right. I tried implementing with `@after.each_step` and it is working now. Posted the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented the following code and it is attaching the screenshot now at the step which fails.

```
 @after.each_step
    def attach_screenshot(step):
        if step.state == "failed":
            step.embed(driver.get_screenshot_as_base64(),
                mime_type='image/png',
                encode_data_to_base64=False)
```